# How to change change Kibana saved search (Discover) with a REST request?

Tags: rest, elasticsearch, kibana

I have query for searching specific occurrences in Kibana, this query is saved among other searches, is there a way I can change it programmatically via for example a REST call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Mohammad said, All metadata related to Kibana is stored under `.kibana` index in elasticsearch cluster. All searches, visualization, dashboards are stored in their respective types in `.kibana` index. e.g searches are stored under `search` type in `.kibana` index.

Get all searches by executing following command:

```
GET /.kibana/search/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

Retrieve `search-id` for which you want to update the query from the above results.

Now you can update that specific `search` document by using `_update` API as shown below:

```
POST /.kibana/search/<search-id>/_update
{
   "doc" : {
      "kibanaSavedObjectMeta":{ "searchSourceJSON": """{"index":"test-*","query":{"query_string":{"query":"id:2","analyze_wildcard":true}},"filter":[],"highlight":{"pre_tags":["@kibana-highlighted-field@"],"post_tags":["@/kibana-highlighted-field@"],"fields":{"*":{}},"require_field_match":false,"fragment_size":2147483647}}"""
   }
   }
}
```

Consider the following warning message from Kibana if you are not advanced user:

> **Proceed with caution!**
>
> Modifying objects is for advanced users only. Object properties are
>   not validated and invalid objects could cause errors, data loss, or
>   worse. Unless someone with intimate knowledge of the code told you to
>   be in here, you probably shouldn’t be.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is stored in `.kibana` index and you can update your settings by a `put request` into elasticsearch but it's not recommended.
You can edit your saved search in `kibana/settings/objects`.