# How to fetch ALL saved searches (discover) in Kibana via a REST GET?

Tags: rest, elasticsearch, kibana

I tried to leverage the solution described in this post using fiddler : [How to change change Kibana saved search (Discover) with a REST request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43988254/how-to-change-change-kibana-saved-search-discover-with-a-rest-request)

Also I had a look at: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/export-saved-objects-via-rest-api/72028/2

My problem is that even though the json returned by my get rest request has the right value for the number of definitions, it does not embed them all (only 10 out of 34 search definitions), is there like a index + count option for fetching all of them.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok just found a workaround, actually, I should have thought about that before... 
Here is what I have done, basically listened to the queries from the browser using fiddler (using the https decrypt option) on:

1. Settings tab
2. Saved objects
3. Searches

It seems that there is a size parameter that I was not really aware of (like I said in my initial post, thought about an index + count / limit like in any db system)

```
POST my_kibana_url/elasticsearch/.kibana/visualization/_search?size=100 HTTP/1.1
{"query":{"match_all":{}}}
```

And look at the count value to check whether the sizes of all the requests accumulated is matching that number.